# pymongo update not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to update a row in a mongoDB using pymongo. It seems to all work, except that it doesn't actually update the row! Is there something I'm missing (like a flush command?). Code snippet below:

```
In [161]: articles = connection.journals.articles.find()
In [162]: articles[0]['_id']
Out[162]: ObjectId('4ee61fc0df04c08c5c510b51')

In [163]: articles[0]['newfield'] = 'Test'

In [164]: connection.journals.articles.update({'_id': articles[0]['_id']}, articles[0], safe=True)
Out[164]: 
{u'connectionId': 62,
 u'err': None,
 u'n': 1,
 u'ok': 1.0,
 u'updatedExisting': True}

In [165]: articles = connection.journals.articles.find()

In [166]: articles[0]['_id']
Out[166]: ObjectId('4ee61fc0df04c08c5c510b51')

In [167]: articles[0]['newfield']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

script.py in <module>()
----> 1 
      2 
      3 
      4 
      5 

KeyError: 'newfield'
```

Comment: Ok it seems like updating `articles[0]` doesn't actually change the object! Making a copy through `article=articles[0]` first works ...

Comment: I think `connection.journals.articles.save(articles[0])` made for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [PyMongo Cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor), the result of a `find()` call, isn't actually a list, it just implements `__getitem__` to emulate list-like access. In fact, each time you use item-access notation, it performs a new query against the database with an appropriate `skip()` and `limit()` set in order to return the item you're looking for. So, as you suspected in the comments, modifying the result of `articles[0]` won't work, but making a reference to the result of `articles[0]`, then modifying and using that in `update()` will work.

You should also know that under certain circumstances (basically, if a modification causes the document to grow beyond the free space available "next" to it) the document might be moved on disk/in memory by MongoDB. Since you are not using `sort()` in your `find()` call, you are getting results in an undefined order. When documents move, the order of results in the `find()` call may change if documents have moved.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that might help you understand what's going on:

```
# make a connection
>>> import pymongo
>>> articles = pymongo.Connection()['test']['articles']

# insert an article and print out it's contents (make sure it's there)
>>> articles.insert({"title": "tyler's article"})
>>> article = articles.find_one()
>>> article
{u'_id': ObjectId('4f0b353c096f762312000002'), u'title': u"tyler's article"}

# update the title to something new
>>> article['title'] = "test"

# save it
>>> articles.save(article)

# check to see if it changed
>>> print articles.find_one()
{u'_id': ObjectId('4f0b353c096f762312000002'), u'title': u'test'}
```